# Parsing complex data to two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, regex

From the sample data below,

> "i:0;s:3:\"471\";s:2:\"id\";s:3:\"471\";i:1;s:24:\"SIP/61123456999-0000004c\";s:9:\"sessionid\";s:24:\"SIP/61123456999-0000004c\";i:2;s:13:\"1413095709.76\";s:8:\"uniqueid\";s:13:\"1413095709.76\";i:3;s:0:\"\";s:12:\"nasipaddress\";s:0:\"\";i:4;s:19:\"2014-10-12 18:35:23\";s:9:\"starttime\";s:19:\"2014-10-12 18:35:23\";i:5;s:19:\"2014-10-12 18:35:23\";s:8:\"stoptime\";s:19:\"2014-10-12 18:35:23\";i:6;s:1:\"0\";s:11:\"sessiontime\";s:1:\"0\";i:7;s:11:\"61412123948\";s:13:\"calledstation\";s:11:\"61412123948\";i:8;s:2:\"-0\";s:11:\"sessionbill\";s:2:\"-0\";i:9;s:1:\"1\";s:14:\"id_tariffgroup\";s:1:\"1\";i:10;s:1:\"6\";s:13:\"id_tariffplan\";s:1:\"6\";i:11;s:5:\"31525\";s:11:\"id_ratecard\";s:5:\"31525\";i:12;s:1:\"1\";s:8:\"id_trunk\";s:1:\"1\";i:13;s:1:\"0\";s:6:\"sipiax\";s:1:\"0\";i:14;s:11:\"61123456999\";s:3:\"src\";s:11:\"61123456999\";i:15;N;s:6:\"id_did\";N;i:16;s:7:\"0.00000\";s:7:\"buycost\";s:7:\"0.00000\";i:17;N;s:21:\"id_card_package_offer\";N;i:18;s:1:\"0\";s:16:\"real_sessiontime\";s:1:\"0\";i:19;s:13:\"0061412123948\";s:4:\"dnid\";s:13:\"0061412123948\";i:20;s:1:\"4\";s:16:\"terminatecauseid\";s:1:\"4\";i:21;s:3:\"614\";s:11:\"destination\";s:6:\"AUSMOB\";i:22;s:3:\"614\";s:6:\"prefix\";s:3:\"614\";i:23;s:6:\"AUSMOB\";"

I am trying to put the value between the `i:\d*` and `s:\d*` delimiters into a two dimensional array like:

```
[0]["471"]
[0]["id"]
[0]["471"]

[1]["SIP/61123456999-0000004c"]
[1]["sessionid"]
[1]["SIP/61123456999-0000004c"]

[2]["1413095709.76"]
[2]["uniqueid"]
[2]["1413095709.76"]

etc.
```

What is the best way to do this in **Ruby**?

Comment: So the result should be `[["471", "id", "471"], ["SIP/...", "sessionid", "SIP/..."], ...`? The data looks similar to BEN coding used in torrent file (with some slight differences).

Comment: This looks very much like serialized PHP data structure. Consider using https://rubygems.org/gems/php-serialize. How did you get this sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works as well:

```
str.gsub(/s:\d+:/,'').split(/i:\d+;/)[1..-1].map { |s| s.split(';') }
  #=> [["\"471\"", "\"id\"", "\"471\""],
  #    ["\"SIP/61123456999-0000004c\"", "\"sessionid\"",
  #     "\"SIP/61123456999-0000004c\""],
  #    ["\"1413095709.76\"", "\"uniqueid\"", "\"1413095709.76\""],
  #    ...
  #    ["\"614\"", "\"prefix\"", "\"614\""],
  #    ["\"AUSMOB\""]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\\";]+)\\[^\\]*\\"([^\\";]+)\\[^\\]*\\"([^\\";]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Use `g` flag.Grab the captures or matches.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/39

Comment: The solution needs to be in Ruby and pasting the regex above to http://rubular.com/ returned error.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. Your solution is correct. Copy-pasted the wrong sample data to the regex tester. Cheers !